# Multiple Conditions Django Template

Tags: python, django, if-statement, for-loop

I'm currently trying to use (3) conditions that are based on information in a table called `Tld`.

**views.py**

```
#check if current auth. user has ENTERED any domains
User_Tld_Entered = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoClient_id=request.user)

#check if current auth. user has any UNAUTHORIZED domains
User_No_Auth_Tld = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoClient_id=request.user,auth=0)

#check if current auth. user has any AUTHORIZED domains
User_Auth_Tld = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoClient_id=request.user,auth=1)
```

**templates.py**

```
{% if User_Tld_Entered == 0  %} <!-- show ADD TLD form -->

    <h1>show ADD TLD form</h1>

{% elif User_No_Auth_Tld > 0 %} <!--display unauth domains, with auth link-->

    <h1>display unauth domains, with auth link</h1>
        {% for unauth_domain in User_No_Auth_Tld %}
            {{ unauth_domain }}
        {% endfor %}

{% elif User_Auth_Tld > 0 %} <!--display auth domains, with scan form-->
    <h1>show diff form</h1>
{% endif %}
```

When I access my template, it shows `<h1>display unauth domains, with auth link</h1>`, but doesn't show anything from the `for()`.

This is strange, because it should be showing the original `if()` statement value of `<h1>show ADD TLD form</h1>` as the `Tld` table has no data in it, it seems strange it would fall into that `elif User_No_Auth_Tld > 0` statement.

Is something with my views.py vars that is incorrect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User_Tld_Entered`, `User_No_Auth_Tld`, and `User_Auth_Tld` are querysets, not integers. To test whether they're empty, you should use code like

```
{% if not User_Tld_Entered %}
     ...
{% elif User_No_Auth_Tld %}
     ...
{% elif User_Auth_Tld %}
     ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Bingo! You rock! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called `.count()` on any of the querysets. Your comparisons are just being made against the query objects. A query object by itself is always greater than 0, even if the actual results from the query would be empty.

Comment: Would that be: User_Tld_Entered = Tld.objects.filter(FKtoClient_id=request.user).count()  for example?